# How to edit elements in plist file

Tags: objective-c, plist

I have a Settings.plist and I want to edit some values in this file.

My function to edit/writing is:

```
- (void) setParamWithName: (NSString*) Name withValue: (NSString*) Value {

// get paths from root direcory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// get documents path
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
// get the path to plist file
NSString *plistPath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Settings.plist"];

// check to see if Data.plist exists in documents
if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:plistPath])
{
    // if not in documents, get property list from main bundle
    plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Settings" ofType:@"plist"];
}

// read property list into memory as an NSData object
NSData *plistXML = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsAtPath:plistPath];
NSString *errorDesc = nil;
NSPropertyListFormat format;
// convert static property list into dictionary object
NSDictionary *temp = (NSDictionary *)[NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListFromData:plistXML mutabilityOption:NSPropertyListMutableContainersAndLeaves format:&format errorDescription:&errorDesc];
if (!temp)
{
    NSLog(@"Error reading plist: %@, format: %d", errorDesc, format);
}

// checking if element exists, if yes overwriting

// if element not exists adding new element


[temp writeToFile:plistPath atomically:YES];
```

}

This function read and write (with te same values) Settings.plist.

I do not have any idea (my knowledge about objective-c is not enough) how to add new element or edit existing element. Can anyone help mi with this issue?

Comment: as you can see, your plist contains a NSDictionary, so to add something you just need to add an element to the dictionary that you read and then save it.

to add an element into a dictionary you have to do this 
[myDictionary setValue:@"myValue" forKey:@"myElement"];

Comment: thank you, this line: [temp setValue:Value forKey:Name]; was exactly what I needed.

Comment: Use setObject:forKey: for dictionaries. The other one gets into the key value coding mechanism, which behaves similarly in some cases but breaks in others.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's easier as you think.

Once you got the path of the file read it into a NSDictionary. Make a mutable copy of that dictionary with mutableCopy and NSMutableDictionary.
Now edit that mutable dictionary as you like (add s.th., remove s.th., edit s.th. and so on).

Now that you're done you can write it back to the old path as you did with temp.

Your main problem is that you're not working with a mutable version of that dicitionary. It'd make your life much easier.